# java remove punctuation recursive method

Tags: java, recursion, methods, call

I made a method to remove some punctuation from a String but its just returning the word passed in the parameter w/ the punctuation included, can anyone spot what's wrong?

```
public static String removePunctuation(String word) {

    if (word.charAt(0) >= 32 && word.charAt(0) <= 46) {
        if(word.length() == 1){
            return "";
        } else {
        return removePunctuation(word.substring(1));
        }
    } else {
        if(word.length() == 1){
            return "" + word.charAt(0);
        } else {
        return word.charAt(0) + removePunctuation(word.substring(1));
        }
    }
}//end method
```

Comment: Please use a debugger for these things; they're designed to solve this exact kind of problem.

Comment: By the way, you can probably simplify this if your base case is the empty string, not a string with 1 character in it.  Then it just becomes `if (word.isEmpty()) return word; ...` and you get rid of the nasty nested `if`s.

Comment: Please provide example input and output so we can see the result.

Comment: oops case closed, my ascii code values did not include all the punctuation marks i was testing for

Comment: @user3189506, I'm glad you found the problem.  Since both the people who took the time to answer correctly identified the problem, please accept one of their answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran the code you provided with the input:

`h.ello` and got the output `hello`

I am seeing a fully functional method here. I presume the punctuation you are trying to remove is not part of the ASCII range you provided in the if statement. Check your ASCII values against a chart.

[ASCII values chart to compare with](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html)

Without including the proper values the input:

`h[ello` will return the output `h[ello` because the `[` is ASCII value 91, which is outside the range you provided:
`>= 32 && <= 46`

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your algorithm. Most likely your range (32-46) doesn't include all the punctuation you're trying to remove. For example, `?` is 63, so it will not get removed.